# How do dedicated light meters account for light transmittance?

Tags: exposure, metering, light-meter, light-transmission

[Dedicated light meters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/why-use-a-dedicated-light-meter-instead-of-the-one-built-into-the-camera) seem to be well-regarded for their versatility and accuracy of metering.

What puzzles me about them is **how can they account for the different light transmittance of different lenses?** It's easy for an in-camera metering system that meters [through the lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/what-does-ttl-mean) so any peculiarity in transmittance is already applied to light when it reaches the metering sensor. But a standalone meter does not have the privilege of looking at the world through the lens it meters for. I tried looking it up in [some light meter manuals](http://www.sekonic.com/Support/InstructionManualUserGuideDownload.aspx) and [Sekonic FAQ](http://www.sekonic.com/Support/FAQs/General-metering-techniques.aspx), but this issue was not touched upon at all.

This leaves several variants how it could be handled -

- light meter uses [T-stops](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21940/what-is-t-number-t-stop) for aperture display/input, and photographer is expected to perform the adjustments to and from [F-stops](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/594/what-does-f-stop-mean) (which are used by cameras);
- light meter assumes some median transmittance of lenses of its era, and automatically accounts for that;
- photographers simply ignore the matter - even a 75% transmitting lens will be off only by about half a stop, no big deal;
- each light meter used is expected to know that you have to dial in some exposure compensation to account for the light loss;
- ...

So how does it work in real world?

Comment: My guess is it's just ignored all mediums are going to have exposure latitude of plus or minus half a stop. And the difference in transmission between lenses will be even less than that so people probably get used to applying a slight correction to whatever the lightmeter says regardless of the lens.

Comment: Probably all of those: Sekonic meters at least allow you to manually adjust their calibration (which you described as "exposure compensation").

Comment: It would take 71% transmittance to lose 1/2 f-stop, so for most cases you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not knowing the transmittance of your lenses is really bothering you, you could test them and see as [this DPReview user did](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1030&message=33785655). Most of the lenses tested, about 25 Nikon lenses, averaged in the 80-90% light transmittance (telephoto lenses were less). Compensate accordingly. In the real world of photography, though, a safe assumption is that most don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Like you this bothered me as well. Depending on the lens, the exposure was always 
underexposed to some degree. I use a Sekonic L-758DR, but in the end I don't calibrate using the provided software and tests required.  My gear is Nikon.

Effectively their camera calibration procedure takes lens transmission loss into account, along with many other variables I didn't want to get into.  There has to be something simpler.

Eureka! I discovered that DXO Mark tests lenses in addition to their reference sensor evaluations and a myriad of others I'm sure. To my total surprise lens transmission loss is identified for literally hundreds of lens. So off I go with numbers in hand. For each lens I dial in the loss as compensation and the exposure is bang on.

For every lens there is a mechanical term called f-stop that is universal for all lens. Due to the light loss within a lens there is also t-stop. For example my 105mm f/2.8 t-stop is t/3.4 and my 200-400mm f/4 is t/4.9. Perhaps not significant for some lens but I now dial in the appropriate loss as required.

Trust this helps